# Signup Form works in my localhost but in the goddady server

Tags: php, mysql

The following code works fine in my localhost, however, when I uploaded the file to the GoDaddy hosting am unable to signup. When i run the same code i receive no error what so ever and the values are inserted to my database. please help me.

```
   <?php
    require_once "core/init.php";  
    $output ='';
        if(Input::exists()){
        if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))){
                    $validate = new Validation();
                    $validatation = $validate->check($_POST, 
                            array(      
                                    'email'       =>array(
                                                    'requierd'=>true,
                                                    'min'=>5,
                                                    'max'=>400,
                                                    'unique'=>'customer'),
                                    'username'    =>array(

                                                    'requierd'=>true,
                                                    'min'     => 5,
                                                    'max'     => 50
                                    ),
                                    'password'    =>array(
                                                    'requierd'=>true,
                                                    'min'=> 9

                                    ),
                                    'repassword'  =>array(
                                                    'requierd'=> true,
                                                    'matches' => 'password'
                                    ),
                                    'userType'    =>array(
                                                    'requierd'=> true,
                                    )
                                 )
                        );
                        //Storing error bellow.                 
                    if($validate->passed()){
                            //$output.= 'You have been successfully registerd';             
                            $customer = new Customer();
                            $salt = Hash::salt(32);
                            $usertype =Input::get('userType');
                            try{
                                $customer->create(array(
                                    'username'  =>  Input::get('email'),
                                    'password'  =>               Hash::make(Input::get('password'), $salt),
                                    'salt'      =>  $salt,
                                    'name'      =>  Input::get('username'),
                                    'joined'    =>  date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                                    'group'     =>  Input::get('userType')  
                                ));

                                    Session::flash('home', 'You have been        registerd and can now log in!');
                                    Redirect::to('login.php');

                        }catch(Exception $e){ die($e->getMessage()." Here is the error "); }    
                    }else{
                            $output.='<div class="col-md-12"><div class="jumbotron"><p>';
                                            //output errors
                                            $x =0;
                                            foreach($validate->errors() as $key => $error){
                                                $output.= $error. ', ';
                                            }
                            $output.='</p></div></div>';
                    }
            }           
    }
?>
<?php include"_/php/header.php";?> 
<section class="container">     
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $output; ?>  
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">                       
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h2> Sign Up</h2>
                    </div>
                            <form class="panel-body" action="signup.php" method="post" name="register" id="register">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo escap(Input::get('email')); ?>"/>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="username">Username</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" value="<?php echo escap(Input::get('username')); ?>"/>
                                            <small>This Name will appear when your application is listed, your real name wont be seen except by bankers. </small>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">    
                                            <label for="password">Create Password</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">    
                                            <label for="repassword">Confirm Password</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="password" id="repassword" name="repassword" placeholder="Repassword" value=""/>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="type">What is you'r roll</label>
                                            <select id="type" name="userType" class="form-control required" >
                                                    <option value="2">Borrower</option>
                                                    <option value="1">Creditor</option> 
                                            </select>
                                    </div>




                                    <div class="checkbox">          
                                            <label>
                                                <input class="form-control required" id="terms" name="terms"  value="off" type="checkbox" unchecked>
                                                Terms and Condition

                                            </label>


                                    </div>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="token"  value="<?php echo Token::generate();?>">
                                    <input class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="submit" name="register" value="Sign Up">

                            </form>
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                <h4>Have an account? Log in<h4>
                            </div>      
            </div>
        </div><!--End col-md-6 -->  
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>        
     </div><!--End row-->
</section><!--End section-->
    <!-- Javascript -->
<?php include"_/php/footer.php"; ?>
```

Bellow are some of the methods that i used.

```
    public static function exists($type = "post"){

        switch($type){

                    case 'post':
                                return (!empty($_POST)) ? true :false;
                            break;  

                    case 'get':
                                return (!empty($_GET)) ? true :false;
                            break;

                            default:
                                return false;   
                            break;
        }                   


    }   

    public static function get($item){

            if(isset($_POST[$item])){

                return $_POST[$item];

            }else if(isset( $_GET[$item] )){

                return $_GET[$item];    

            }
            return '';
    }
```

and another Method

```
public function check($source, $items=array()){
                //$source is the data that is passed, which is in $_POST
                //$item is are the rules such as the requierd, min, and max etc...

                foreach($items as $item => $rules){

                        foreach($rules as $rule => $rule_value){

                            $value = trim($source[$item]);
                            $item = escap($item);

                            if($rule === 'requierd' && empty($value)){
                                $this->addError("{$item} is requierd");     
                            }else if(!empty($value)){

                                    switch($rule){
                                        case 'min':
                                                    if(strlen($value) < $rule_value){
                                                            $this->AddError("{$item} must be a minimum of {$rule_value} charcters.");                                       
                                                    }

                                        break;
                                        case 'max':

                                                    if(strlen($value) > $rule_value){
                                                            $this->AddError("{$item} must not be more then {$rule_value} charcters.");                                      
                                                    }


                                        break;

                                        case 'matches':
                                                if($value != $source[$rule_value])
                                                $this->addError("Password field must matche Confirm-Password field");       

                                        break;
                                        /*                      
                                        case 'unique':
                                                $check = $this->_db->get($rule_value, array($item, '=', $value));
                                                if($check->count()){
                                                    $this->addError("{$item} already exists");
                                                }
                                        break;
                                        */
                                    }
                            }
                            //comments goes here!!!!!!
                        }
                }       
                if(empty($this->_errors)){          
                    $this->_passed = true;
                }   
                return $this;
        }


public function create($fields = array()){
                if(!$this->_db->insert('customer', $fields)){

                    throw new Exception('There was a problem creating an account.');
                }
            }



        public function insert($table, $fields=array()){

                    $keys= array_keys($fields);
                    $values = '';
                    $x=1;
                    foreach($fields as $field){
                        $values .= '?';
                        if($x < count($fields)){
                            $values .= ', ';
                        }
                        $x++;
                    }
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table}(`".implode('`, `',$keys)."`)VALUES({$values})";
                    if(!$this->query($sql,$fields)->error()){
                        return true;
                    }
                return false;
        }
```

Please help me i have following a tutorial and i was able to make it work in my localhost but no in the godaddy server. Your support is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any errors on GoDaddy?

Comment: no that is the problem

Comment: You're checking the error logs?

Comment: i do not know where can i check the error code in godaddy.com can you please assist me on where can i find the error code

Comment: You need to check with GoDaddy for access to the error logs.